# Layout issue while loading an image on Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Loading an image that is larger than the width of a Galaxy Tab 2 P5100 (running 4.1.2) into an ImageView adds some sort of top/bottom padding to the loaded image.

Here's a screenshot with `Show layout boundaries` turned on:

[image: wrong alignment]

Here's how it should look (from a Nexus 10 running 4.4.2):

[image: correct alignment]

The code I use (for both examples above) is

```
public class ImageBugActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bug);

        // This bug is still reproducible if I use the
        // Universal-Image-Loader library or if I change the dimensions of 
        // the image to a different width
        loadImage("http://placehold.it/1600x1000", (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image));
    }

    private void loadImage(final String url, final ImageView view) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("loadImage", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

And the layout file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On a Galaxy Tab 2 the image below it is pushed to the center of the remaining space." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does this seem to be an Android/Samsung bug or am I making a dumb mistake?

Comment: Try to set 'Show layout boundaries' option to true in System settings->Developer options. Then open app & check where boundaries are

Comment: @SamN-a: thanks! It doesn't seem to suggest a solution, but I updated the screenshots.

Comment: Try changing layout to RelativeLayout. You'll have to add some other modifications like adding alignParentTop, layout_below, but it may be worth it. Currently I think it is a bug, because this behaviouer is unexpected

Comment: You're right, using a RelativeLayout looks like the right way to go. However `android:scaleType="fitStart"` is an easier fix. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `android:scaleType` of the `ImageView` to `"fitStart"` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `"match_parent"` for `layout_height` of the ImageView.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Note that the code I have posted above works perfectly on Nexus 10 devices.